# Change "Specify your own value:" to "Other" in a Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need an easy way to change "Specify your own value:" to "Other" in a Sharepoint 365 form (NewForm and EditForm). I've seen references to JQuery and Java, but since I'm not a programmer is there something more simplicstic I can do?

If not can anyone provide a step by step on how to do it?

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done only programmatically.

Try this solution (step-by-step):
1. Open your list in browser Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer because you may receive later some unexpected errors with Script Editor web part in other browsers. If you don't have IE then use other browser but be warning that when you Insert code in Script Editor web part you can see page with error. Just close this page. Your script already successfully added to page. You can check this.
2. If you don't see ribbon on top of page with buttons when click on area with list items and ribbon must be appeared.
3. Click "List" tab -> "Customize List" group -> "Form Web Parts" dropdown -> click "Default New Form" (repeat current and following steps for "Default Edit Form").
You will be redirected to page: 
"`http://<SERVER>/sites/Test/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/TestList/NewForm.aspx`" or "`http://<SERVER>/sites/Test1/Lists/Test2/NewForm.aspx`".
4. On opened page click link "Add a Web Part". You will see new panel at the top with web parts to choose.
5. In block "Categories" choose "Media and Content". In block "Parts" choose "Script Editor". Click button "Add".
6. You will see that on page "Script Editor" web part added. Click link EDIT SNIPPET.
7. In opened modal dialog paste following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeFillInLabels() {
    document.querySelectorAll('[for$="FillInButton"]').forEach(function(el){
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace("Specify your own value:", "Other");
    });
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded(changeFillInLabels);
</script>
```

8. Click Insert button.
9. In ribbon on page top click button "Stop Editing".
   You will be redirected to list defult view page.

Now you can create new list item and you will see that text "Specify your own value:" changed on "Other" on New Form.
Repeat 3-9 steps for "Default Edit Form".

I tested it, it works